# Media Library Child Folder Kentico 11

Tags: kentico

I need some assistance with media library Kentico 11.I have a Library with multiple folders inside, each folder has its own images.What I need is to get the direct path of a folder.My structure below, in this case i need the path for "Tops" so that i can pull all the images inside "Tops"

```
>Store(Folder)
>-Clothing(Folder)
     > -Tops(Folder)
       --images(File)
```

Comment: So you're looking for a control to select a folder? Or are you looking for a way to find all images in a "specified" Media library folder? Did you check the API examples https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/media-libraries?

Comment: @DTK, I was looking for images inside a specified folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all images from the folder e.g. Store/Clothing/Tops

You can use something like:

```
var mediaFiles = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFiles()
    .WhereStartsWith("FilePath", "Store/Clothing/Tops");
```

Depending on further requirements you can also add specific file types

```
    .WhereEquals("FileExtension", ".png")
```

or select only from a specific media library

```
    .WhereEquals("FileLibraryID", yourLibrary.LibraryID)
```

If you have access to the Database you can check the Database directly for how the paths are stored:

```
SELECT * FROM Media_File WHERE filepath LIKE 'Store/Clothing/Tops%'
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually used WhereContains()

Comment: Note that when searching using WhereContains() will also return items with the same path but different root.